My SQL trigger does not work on the first input
BEGIN
    DECLARE toplam_cevap INT;
    DECLARE dogru_oran DECIMAL(5,2);

    -- Doğru ve yanlış cevapların toplamı
    SET toplam_cevap = NEW.dogru_cevap_sayisi + NEW.yanlis_cevap_sayisi;

    -- Eğer toplam cevap sayısı 0 veya daha büyükse oranı hesapla
    IF toplam_cevap > 0 THEN
        SET dogru_oran = (NEW.dogru_cevap_sayisi / toplam_cevap) * 100;
    ELSE
        -- Eğer toplam cevap sayısı 0 ise oranı 0 olarak ayarla
        SET dogru_oran = 0;
    END IF;

    -- Yeni değeri atanacak sütunu güncelle
    SET NEW.bilinme_yuzdesi = dogru_oran;
END

In my SQL trigger code above, the known percentage of the first data saved to the database remains constant as the default value.
This is the trigger of the table where correct and incorrect answers are kept in the database of a quiz application. When the user answers the first question correctly or incorrectly, the value in the column that calculates the user's success rate does not change. It works normally after the first value, it just remains as default at the first value.

What kind of trigger is this? UPDATE or INSERT, BEFORE or AFTER?

BEFORE and UPDATE @Barmar

Please post a [mre]. Show sample initial data and the update query.

So it's an UPDATE trigger, and it does nothing on INSERT? This is expected. UPDATE triggers are not run on INSERT.

correct answer = 1, wrong answer = 0, rate = NULL (or whatever default value I gave)
wrong answer = 0, correct answer = 1, rate = NULL (or whatever default value I gave)
correct answer = 1, wrong answer = 1, rate = 50.00% (
it started working correctly)

@BillKarwin I gave the example working style above.

@mysia Provide a sample according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, paragraphs 5 and 3.

PS. Use not a trigger but generated column.
